# Execute a Windows Phone 8.1 Application after deactivation

Tags: c#, .net, lifecycle, windows-phone-8.1, application-lifecycle

I know about the Windows Phone 8.1 Applications lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

But, is it possible to keep active the application when it is not used (after deactivation)?

Is it possible to realize a WP8.1 App that sends some data to a Server at predetermined time intervals? Is it possible to execute code in the App, when it is deactivated?

Comment: I'm not a Windows Phone expert, but this seems like a reasonable question to me. It might be helpful (to the OP and others) if someone could elaborate why it is being downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have tagged your question for WP8.1, apart from [Silverlight apps, there are also Universal/Runtime apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn632732.aspx). It's worth to mention that in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime Apps you have a little different [app lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx).

Any way, when your App is being *Suspended*, *Deactivated*, *Tombstoned* or put into *Not-Running* state, it is being stopped. and there is no way that it will work in Background (with official API and apart from Audioplayers, GPS tracking apps and other specially desinged models for that). A diffrenet case is also an App running under the lock screen (it is possible, but it's not what you are asking for). When you navigate away from your App, then [Suspending event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx) is raised or ([Deactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in WP Silverlight) - note also that you have very limited time with those events to save the state of your App.

There are ways for working in background, apart from [BackgroundAgents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24235223/2681948), starting from Windows Phone 8.1 (both Silverlight and Runtime) you can use [BackgroundTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh977046.aspx). They can be triggered (for example [TimeTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx), [MaintanceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.maintenancetrigger.aspx)) depending on their [Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553523.aspx) - in time intervals and/or upon [special conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj160502.aspx).

[Here is a vary good article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx), and you can also find some information [at this article](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/).

Comment: Thank you Romasz for your answer. About Background Tasks, I've found that I can run tasks as frequently as every 15 minutes. As I explain to George I need to update device's location more frequently. In your knowledge, are there any ways to do it?

Comment: @top_broker In Windows Phone build-in timer works with 30 minute interval (15 min is on Windows). So this way you won't go below that time. AFAIK there is no way to run task faster, but - there are some types of apps which are allowed to run in background continously - AudioAgent, Location Tracking apps. So if you want to update device's location - [check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: I need to continuosly track device's position and send this data to a server. Is this possible, using geolocator? The method geolocator_StatusChanged() can run even if the App is deactivated or can be executed as a background task? if yes, how? (this is what I really need to know :) )

Comment: @top_broker I've tried that yet. Under WP8.0 [when the App tracked location actively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691(v=vs.105).aspx) then the App was allowed to run in the background up to 4 hours (with some other limits). But I'm not sure how this works now in WP8.1 - you will have to check it. Also note that there were some API restriction while running in background.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need a `PeriodicTask`

`Periodic agents run for a small amount of time on a regular recurring interval. Typical scenarios for this type of task include uploading the device’s location and performing small amounts of data synchronization.`

Source: [Backgrounds agents for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you George for your answer. I've read the article and PeriodicTask seems to be what I need, but there are strong limits. A PeriodicTask can execute no more than 1 time per 10 minutes. In my app, I need background agents to update the device's location but I think it is useful to do it more frequently. Is it possible to execute background code more frequently?

Comment: Are you sure about that? As you can see in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx) example, you can run the agent every minute. (At least in debug mode)

Comment: ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest() allows to run agent every minute only (unfortunately) in debug mode but I need this feature also in the final release.

Comment: Can u send me your source to the 10 minute limitation?