# Windows 10 Universal App - Geofence Background task not being triggered

Tags: c#, background-task, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to create a Windows UAP (C#) to constantly log location data in a background task, for now all I'm trying to do is start the background task off of a geofence trigger.

I've followed a lot of guides for how to do this, I've added the entry point in the Package.appxmanifest to "BackgroundTask.LocationBackgroundTask" and selected the location property.

I'm then registering the task using the following:

```
var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = BackgroundTaskName;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = BackgroundTaskEntryPoint;
builder.SetTrigger(new LocationTrigger(LocationTriggerType.Geofence));
var geofenceTask = builder.Register();
```

I use the following code to verify if the background task is registered and it returns true to indicate that the task is registered:

```
public bool IsTaskRegistered()
{
    var Registered = false;
    var entry = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.FirstOrDefault(keyval => keyval.Value.Name == BackgroundTaskName);
    if (entry.Value != null)
        Registered = true;
    return Registered;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the Run method in the background task is just not getting triggered.

To verify the background task itself is all good, I swapped out the trigger type for  `builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.PowerStateChange, true));` (and updated the Package.appxmanifest to have the system event property). This then worked fine as the background task was triggered as I'd expect when I unplugged the power source from my laptop.

The other thing to note is that when debugging I don't see the background task under the Lifecycle Events whereas I do when testing with the SystemTrigger.

The problem does therefore seem to be specific to the geofence triggering. I'm starting to pull my hair out a bit over this so would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Please check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481384/windows-phone-8-1-location-tracking

Comment: Having the same problem on my project. Exactly the same. Starting to think the [LocationTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.locationtrigger.aspx) is just broken...