# Send device's current location to Azure service in Windows 8.1

Tags: azure, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, geofencing

I am developing a location tracking windows mobile app and I want to send my current location to azure service as a background task. Getting current location is done. Currently I show the current location in the app tile. Likewise showing location  in the tile I want to send location to the azure service. But how can I send my current location to azure service continuously so rest of the devices can see the device's location.

So far my code

```
public sealed class BackgroundGeofenceTask : IBackgroundTask
{

    //Azure Service
    //private MobileServiceCollection<Location, Location> items;
    //private IMobileServiceTable<Location> LocationTable = App.WayToSchool5Client.GetTable<Location>();


    BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = null;
    Accelerometer _accelerometer = null;
    Geolocator _locator = new Geolocator();

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        try
        {
            // force gps quality readings
            _locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;

            taskInstance.Canceled += taskInstance_Canceled;

            _accelerometer = Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer.GetDefault();
            _accelerometer.ReportInterval = _accelerometer.MinimumReportInterval > 5000 ? _accelerometer.MinimumReportInterval : 5000;
            _accelerometer.ReadingChanged += accelerometer_ReadingChanged;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Add your chosen analytics here
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    void taskInstance_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        _deferral.Complete();
    }

    async void accelerometer_ReadingChanged(Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer sender, Windows.Devices.Sensors.AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_locator.LocationStatus != PositionStatus.Disabled)
            {
                try
                {
                    Geoposition pos = await _locator.GetGeopositionAsync();

                    XmlDocument xml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Text03);
                    var tileElements = xml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
                    tileElements[0].AppendChild(xml.CreateTextNode(pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude.ToString("f5")));
                    tileElements[1].AppendChild(xml.CreateTextNode(pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString("f5")));
                    tileElements[2].AppendChild(xml.CreateTextNode(pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Altitude.ToString("f0")));
                    TileNotification tile = new TileNotification(xml);
                    TileUpdater updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
                    updater.Update(tile);

                    //Send locationto azure
                    //var db = new Location { ServiceId = "sID", CurrentLatitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString(), CurrentLongitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude.ToString() };
                    //await LocationTable.InsertAsync(db);



                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.HResult != unchecked((int)0x800705b4))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_accelerometer != null)
        {
            _accelerometer.ReadingChanged -= accelerometer_ReadingChanged;
            _accelerometer.ReportInterval = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Location.cs

```
public class Location
{
    public string ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentLatitude { get; set; }
    public string CurrentLongitude { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you please edit your question and clarify?

Comment: I see you've edited it, but still unclear what you're asking. I mean: How did you build your backend? What, exactly, are you stuck on (the communication part? How to represent location? How to store it? How to secure it?). As it stands, this question isn't answerable.

Comment: Edited the question, think it's more understandable

Comment: @ThilinaAkalanka can you show your model class 'Location' please?